# The proper way to use try/except blocks in tasks that can be cancelled

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In essence my question is *when and where is the `asyncio.CancelledError`
exception raised in the coroutine being cancelled?*

I have an application with a couple of async tasks that run in a loop. At some
point I start those tasks like this:

```py
async def connect(self);
    ...
    t1 = asyncio.create_tasks(task1())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(task2())
    ...
    self._workers = [t1, t2, ...]
```

When disconnecting, I cancel the tasks like this:

```py
async def disconnect(self):
    for task in self._workers:
        task.cancel()
```

This has been working fine. The [documentation of `Task.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) says

> The coroutine then has a chance to clean up or even deny the request by suppressing the exception with a
>   `try … … except CancelledError … finally` block. Therefore, unlike `Future.cancel()`, `Task.cancel()` does
>   not guarantee that the Task will be cancelled, although suppressing cancellation completely is
>   not common and is actively discouraged.

so in my workers I avoid doing stuff like this:

```py
async def worker():
    while True:
        ...
        try:
            some work
        except:
            continue
```

but that means that now I have to explicitly put `asyncio.CancelledError` in the
`except` statement:

```py
async def worker():
    while True:
        ...
        try:
            some work
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            raise
        except:
            continue
```

which can be tedious and I also have to make sure that anything that I call from
my worker obliges by this rule.

So now I'm not sure if this is a good practice at all. Now that I'm thinking
about it, I don't even know when exactly the exception is raised. I was
searching for a similar case here in SO and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56052748/1480131) which also
raised the same question *"When will this exception be thrown? And where?"*. The
answer says

> This exception is thrown after `task.cancel()` is called. It is thrown inside the coroutine,
>   where it is caught in the example, and it is then re-raised to be thrown and caught
>   in the awaiting routine.

And while it make sense, this got me thinking: this is async scheduling, the
tasks are not interrupted at any arbitrary place like with threads but they only
"give back control" to the event loop when a task does an `await`. Right?
So that means that checking everywhere whether
`asyncio.CancelledError` was raised might not be necessary. For example, let's
consider this example:

```py
def worker(interval=1):
    while True:
        try:
            # doing some work and no await is called in this block
            sync_call1()
            sync_call2()
            sync_call3()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            raise
        except:
            # deal with error
            pass

        await asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

So I think here the `except asyncio.CancelledError` is unnecessary because this
error cannot "physically" be raised in the `try/block` at all since the thread
in the `try` block will never be interrupted by the event loop. The only place
where this task gives back the control to the event loop is at the `sleep` call,
that is not even in a `try/block` and hence it doesn't suppress the exception. Is
my train of though correct? If so, does that mean that I only have to account
for `asyncio.CancelledError` when I have an `await` in the `try` block? So would
this also be OK, knowing that `worker()` can be cancelled?

```py
def worker(interval=1):
    while True:
        try:
            # doing some work and no await is called in this block
            sync_call1()
            sync_call2()
            sync_call3()
        except:
            # deal with error
            pass

        await asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

And after reading the answer of the other SO question, I think I should also
wait for the cancelled tasks in my `disconnect()` function, do I? Like this?

```py
async def disconnect(self):
    for task in self._workers:
        task.cancel()

    await asyncio.gather(*self._workers)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I think so. `CancelledException` is raised in the `await` expression so `CancelledException` is not raised (BTW, wildcard catch is not good). Besides, `await` tasks being cancelled will raise `CancelledException`. `asyncio.wait` or loop them one by one to sure the tasks all done before return.

Comment: @Aaron aha, ok, thanks. So it would be better to wrap `await asyncio.gather(*self._workers)` in `try/block` so that `disconnect` doesn't raise an exception. That make sense.

Comment: for `asyncio.gather`, the `return_exceptions=True` argument is needed or some tasks may be still scheduled.

Comment: @Aaron nice, that makes sense.

Comment: I would point out that `try: ... except: continue` is an anti-pattern. You should always catch a more specific exception. If you do catch all exceptions, that should be only to perform some cleanup/logging before re-raising it. If you do so, you won't have a problem with `CancelledError`. Also, in Python 3.8 `CancelledError` derives from `BaseException`, which means `except Exception` won't catch it, also resolving the issue.

Comment: @user4815162342 thanks for the suggestion. Because my worker task runs in endless loop, if some minor step fails (aka throws an exception) I'd like to "ok, ignore this cycle, let's start a new one), that's why I have the `try: ... except: continue` there. How would you solve this? Simply with `except Exception: continue`? Thanks for the tip of `CancelledError` deriving from `BaseException`. Is this only in py3.8 or does it also apply to py3.7 and py3.6 as well?

Comment: In Python 3.8 and later you can use `except Exception: continue`, but I'd still log the exception before continuing rather than swallowing it silently. In Python 3.7 and earlier you need to use the pattern you discovered yourself. Your analysis is correct in that if the code you see doesn't contain an awaiting construct, you can't get a `CancelledError` (at least not from `task.cancel`; someone could still raise it manually, but then you probably _want_ to treat is as any other exception). Note that awaiting constructs include `await`, `async for` and `async with`.

Comment: I've now added these comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: if the code doesn't contain an awaiting construct, you can't get a `CancelledError` (at least not from `task.cancel`; someone could still raise it manually, but then you probably want to treat is as any other exception). Note that awaiting constructs include `await`, `async for` and `async with`.

Having said that, I would add that `try: ... except: continue` is an anti-pattern. You should always catch a more specific exception. If you do catch all exceptions, that should be only to perform some cleanup/logging before re-raising it. If you do so, you won't have a problem with `CancelledError`. If you absolutely must catch all exceptions, consider at least *logging* the fact that an exception was raised, so that it doesn't pass silently.

Python 3.8 made it much easier to catch exceptions other than `CancelledError` because it switched to deriving `CancelledError` from `BaseException`. In 3.8 `except Exception` won't catch it, resolving your issue.

To sum it up:

- If you run Python 3.8 and later, use `except Exception: traceback.print_exc(); continue`.
- In Python 3.7 and earlier you need to use the pattern put forth in the question. If it's a lot of typing, you can abstract it into a function, but that will still require some refactoring.

For example, you could define a utility function like this:

```
def run_safe(thunk):
    try:
        thunk()
        return True
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        raise
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It's a shame that `CancelledError` is based on `BaseException` from py3.8 onwards, I still have to support running in py36 and py37, so I have to do the long way.